# If an electron falls into a quantum black hole, does the latter then have a quantum spin of 1/2?

Tags: black-holes, electrons, quantum-spin

Just a hypothetical question: imagine a electron falls into a stationary quantum black hole. Would this black hole then have a quantum spin of $\frac12$? Can we use the Stern–Gerlach experiment to test it?

Answer (score 2):

The only things you can know about a classical black hole are its mass, spin, and electric charge. For a quantum black hole, that would translate to its spin and charges in terms of not just electromagnetism, but the weak and strong forces as well. So, yes, a spin-0 black hole absorbing a spin-1/2 particle would have a spin of 1/2. Absorbing another spin-1/2 particle would have all the usual quantum rules about which spins (0 or 1) the final black hole would have.

If the black hole has a nonzero magnetic moment (which it should if it has nonzero spin and nonzero charge), then the Stern-Gerlach experiment would see the binary splitting.

Comment: What is a “quantum black hole”? It sounds like a non-existing result of the non-existing theory of quantum gravity. The whole point of the no-hair theorem is that charges corresponding to short range forces (week and strong) are not conserved in a black hole. This answer is incorrect.